# Running hundreds of files through single PHP script

Tags: php, xml

I need to run 600 XML files through a script I've made that extracts specific pieces of information and saves each one in JSON format. All 600 XML files are inside a folder ready to be run through the PHP file, I'm now looking for a fast way to do it.

Essentially this is the process the PHP file goes through:

PHP reads single XML file via URL -> locally saves important info in variables -> saves important info into JSON file

Is there a way I can somehow run all 600 XML files through my PHP file?

Thanks

Comment: do you need to run the php file in the browser or would the command line be an option too?

Comment: Depends, are you trying to do this the "right way" or the "quick and dirty" way? The right way is to find the reusable parts of your script and refactor them into classes/methods that can be reused in a loop.

Comment: Yes there is a way, however, why do you ask? I mean what prevents you from doing so?

Comment: Sadly this can not be done without the `jQuery.processSixHundredXmlFiles()` plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the directory containing the XML files and then process them, here are some of the most common way todo that.

[opendir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)

```
<?php
$dir = "/etc/php5/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

You can also use [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Inside the foreach loop of whichever you choose you can use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) or [fread()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) then you can do your conversion to json.

```
<?php
// get contents of a file into a string
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt";
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `file_get_contents` can be used instead of this 4 line code.

Comment: @Javid fgc is just a wrapper for those 4 lines, so it will slightly speed up processing. I did also add fgc content manual link.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone: file_get_contents does memory mapping for the string which you can't do with "those 4 lines", therefore, it's a bit more than just a wrapper. This can increase speed depending on file-size.

Answer (score 0):

Just go ahead and try! You'll probably run into a timeout error. If you do, try configuring the max timeout settings. http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: Perhaps I didn't phrase the question properly. The script I have currently just takes in a file using file_get_contents. That requires a single URL each time, so essentially I'd need to run the script 600 times but I need an easy way to change the file name to each XML file each time if you know what I mean.

Comment: Are the files named in a way that lets you loop through them easily? Like `xml-file1, xml-file2` etc. Then just increment a variable that changes the filename for each run. If not, then try `readdir` which allows you to go through each file in a directory, in the order they're stored.

Comment: @Vienno server max timeout does not guarantee that the browser or proxy will not consider the timeout before.

Answer (score 0):

Joel,

Sounds to me like what you need to is to use readdir

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

This will allow you to get a list of files in a directory to iterate over.

```
$dir = opendir('/path/to/files');
while($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && !is_dir($file)) {
        $parthParts = pathinfo($file);
        if ($pathParts['extension'] === 'xml') {
            runscripton($file);
        }
    }
}
closedir($dir);
```

Comment: You may want to ensure that you are making sure the $file isn't another directory or ., .. or ... entities.

IE

Answer (score 0):

First, write a function that gets an XML file name, and after processing, returns the results in php array or JSON (Based on how you need your code to be).

To write this function, you need to parse XML (http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php).

To work with JSON in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Then, write your main code. Your main code should enumerate all XML files in the folder, and then call your function for each file, and gather/generate JSON using information returned by the function.

You might need `readdir` to gather all of XML files in the folder. (http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php)

Don't forget to increase time limit as long as there are lots of XML files and the process might take long so a timeout error would occur. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)